# planar graph orientation

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that a simple planar graph has an orientation so that the in-degree of every
node is at most 3. If the graph, in addition, is bipartite, then there is an orientation so that the in-degree of every node is at most 2.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to prove these two statements

Comment: My first thought is that it's enough to do it if the graph is maximal planar.  Add edges until every face is a triangle; solve the problem; delete the added edges.  Example $3$ in [these slides](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~felsner/Slides/uab-doccourse.pdf) suggests a way to do it (with out-degree $3$ instead on in-degree $3$)  but I don't know if it works in general, or how to prove it if it does work.  Good luck!

Comment: On reflection, I don't really understand that example.  It seems to say that the out-degree of every outer vertex is $0$, but that's plainly impossible.  How is an edge joining two outer vertices to be oriented?